# UITableViewCell setSelected:animated called twice on iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` on my iPhone app for which I have a custom `setSelected:animated` method. My app works perfectly on iPhone, however, I started to port my app to iPad. I've copied the exact same storyboard, haven't changed anything, but now my `setSelected:animated` method is called twice (with the same parameters) when I select my cell. I could "handle" this case by checking if iPad etc. but it would be a bad practice. What could be the reason that it's called once on iPhone but twice on iPad? (both iOS 7.0.3) The table view's properties are exactly the same (I've copied the iPhone storyboard file).

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    isSelected = selected;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    if(selected){
        SocialMatchAppDelegate *del = (SocialMatchAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        del.selectedUser = self.user;
        [del.resultViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewProfile" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code for analysing?

Comment: I've added the `setSelected:animated` code

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu there's nothing wrong with that code and therefore I imagine that it's something to do with the Storyboard.

Comment: I've copied the exact storyboard from iPhone. File-wise copy paste. It (table view or table view cell) just behaves differently on the iPhone and the iPad, even with the exact same iOS version (I am using simulator)

Comment: How do you have the delegate set up? Is it from the Storyboard? Maybe try removing it and adding it again to see what happens.

Comment: It's actually bad practice to perform that kind of action inside a tableviewcell, too. You should use the tableview's delegate instead: tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is the right place to put such logic.

Comment: @Lukas yep, it'd be a good idea to put the logic to that method as a practice, but still, I want to solve the `setSelected:animated` being called twice as it may create confusion in the future and setNeedsDisplay may become computationally expensive for big views. not very important, but why call it twice?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with similar code done in swift. I also have a universal version of storyboard, so same storyboard for both, iPhone and iPad, I also discovered that setSelected is called twice on iPad - if I change the simulator to iPhone (any of 'em).. Issue doesn't exist..

What would be a best way to avoid double selection set?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this is a normal behavior if you're using iPad.

In order to stop getting multiple "setSelected:YES" or multiple "setSelected:NO", all you have to do is this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Now, 1 click on any cell gives you:

- 1 entry of setSelected:YES animated:NO
- 1 entry of tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
- 1 entry of setSelected:NO animated:YES

Comment: why is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Where did `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected` call in your source?

If it is in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Using this instead

`[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];`

Comment: I haven't called it. I just selected it by touching it :)